# PostgreSQL : Row Counts of Every Table in Schema Based on Specific Column and Conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

I need to find a row count of a specific column says 'Gender' in a schema that contain only null values. I have more than hundreds schema and each schema have more than 10 tables so I also need to group it based on the schema name. How can I achieve this?

Comment: provide some sample data and desire output to help us vizualize your problem.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table to store the table name and row count based on your condition,

```
-- Table: test.row_count

-- DROP TABLE test.row_count;

CREATE TABLE test.row_count
(
  table_name character varying,
  count integer
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE test.row_count
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Below code will help you to store the row count and table name in above table,

```
-- Function: retrive_row_count()

-- DROP FUNCTION retrive_row_count();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrive_row_count()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
  v_table text;
BEGIN

FOR v_table IN
    SELECT table_schema||'.'||table_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE column_name = 'gender'
LOOP

   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test.row_count(table_name , count) SELECT '''||v_table || ''' , COUNT(*) FROM '||v_table || ' WHERE  gender IS NULL' ;



END LOOP;

return 1;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION retrive_row_count()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Hi @Mohit thank you for your replied. I have tried your solution it give me successful query however I am not sure where I should check the result. I run  both query you gave with a little tweak. I change first query to something like this  CREATE TABLE information_schema.row_count instead of 'test' since test give me error.

Comment: Hi zt.az,  "test" is one of the schema on my machine.  You can use any table name u want.   e.g use public.row_count .  Make sure you also change in table name in procedure "retrive_row_count()".

Comment: ok thanks mohit will try it and give feedback later.thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I have tried to run it the query return no error however no data is inserted into the table, Something missing in the SQL query perhaps?

Comment: What if i want to group the row count by schema name?

Comment: use this,    DECLARE
  v_table record;
BEGIN

FOR v_table IN
 SELECT table_schema, table_name 
 FROM information_schema.columns 
 WHERE column_name = 'gender'
LOOP
   
   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test.row_count_a(table_name , count) SELECT '''||v_table.table_schema || ''' , COUNT(*) FROM '||v_table.table_schema || '.'
   
   ||v_table.table_name ||' WHERE  gender IS NULL' ;

Comment: Hi Mohit. it works thanks! Just wondering is it possible to have a few column_name in one function ? because I tried to count few number of column other than gender and it didnt work